# Cannot spoof MAC address on MacBook (since 2018) Mojave (10.14.5)

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, mac-address

I'm having trouble spoofing my mac address on Mojave OS.

I used the following bash script:

```
NEW_MAC=$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport --disassociate
sudo ifconfig en0 lladdr $NEW_MAC
sudo networksetup -detectnewhardware
```

There aren't errors but the same not work (I have tried also with other solutions).

Comment: What Mac, specifically? There was talk on the dev forum that this has been intentionally disabled on Macs since 2018 - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106768

Comment: This is, even if it would work, a completely bad idea. This is not how you ever should generate random Mac addresses.

Comment: @MaxRied - tbh, I've never seen any point to spoofed MAC addresses anyway [let alone ones with random mfr IDs], unless it's like phones do & don't present their real one until a secure connection has been established.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have MacBook Pro since 2018, unfair.

Comment: @MaxRied ok, just to understand where I can get more information about this? I read it here http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/10/random-mac-address-generator/

Comment: @LorenzoDisidoro There is a bit in your Mac address, that indicates that it's a multicast address. If it's set, most switches will discard it if it is used as a source address.